# Get List with 5000 items on the Site Collections

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Im trying to Get all the of the list in the Site Collections.

The script below just get the List in the specific site collection and this is working properly.

```
   #environment variables 
   $username = "user.name@xxx.com"
   $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString
   $url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxx"

   $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

   #add SharePoint Online DLL - update the location if required
   $programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")
   add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'  

   # connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
   $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
   $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
   $ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

   #get all the sub webs
   $Web = $ctx.Web  
   $ctx.Load($web)  
   $ctx.Load($web.Webs)    
   $ctx.executeQuery()

   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "There are:" $web.Webs.Count "sub webs in this site collection"

   #get all the lists 
   foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)
   {
       $lists = $subweb.Lists
       $ctx.Load($lists)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


       #output the list details
       Foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
    if ($list.ItemCount -gt 5000)
           { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url
    Write-Host "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"
           }


    }
   }
```

When i try to modify it to get lists in all of the site collection. It errored out. Here is the script that i modify.

```
   #environment variables 
   $username = "user.name@xxxx.com"
   $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString
   $url = get-content "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\PowershellScripts\sites.txt"

   $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

   #add SharePoint Online DLL - update the location if required
   $programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")
   add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'  

   # connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
   $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
   $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
   $ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

   #get all the sub webs
   $Web = $ctx.Web  
   $ctx.Load($web)  
   $ctx.Load($web.Webs)    
   $ctx.executeQuery()


   foreach($urls in $url)
   {
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "There are:" $web.Webs.Count "sub webs in this site collection"
   #get all the lists 
   foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)
   {
       $lists = $subweb.Lists
       $ctx.Load($lists)
       $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

       #output the list details
       Foreach ($list in $lists)
    {
    if ($list.ItemCount -gt 5000)
           { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url
    Write-Host "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"
           }


        }
   }
   }
```

This is the error.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Users\joshua.maniquiz\Documents\PowershellScripts\GetAllSubWebsandListswithItemCounts.ps1:22
>   char:1 + $ctx.executeQuery() + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvokeMethodOnNull There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection There
>   are: 0 sub webs in this site collection There are: 0 sub webs in this
>   site collection There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection There
>   are: 0 sub webs in this site collection

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What error are you seeing? Also, what is the value of `$url` in your latter script, the file name `sites.txt` suggest multiple sites. When you initialize the `ClientContext($url)`, it should contain only one site at a time. Finally, have a look at the SharePoint PnP PowerShell cmdlets :) They make common PowerShell scripting tasks much more enjoyable, https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell.

Comment: This is the error. 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\joshua.maniquiz\Documents\PowershellScripts\GetAllSubWebsandListswithItemCounts.ps1:22 char:1
+ $ctx.executeQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection
There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection
There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection
There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection
There are: 0 sub webs in this site collection

Comment: the value of the url of my later script is the specific site where it worked. However when i try to get the content of the Sites.txt where the URL's are located it errored out.

Comment: Don't put important information into comments where it is hardly readable. Instead [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50171570/edit) your question so follow up readers don't have to sieve through all comments. Also proper indenting helps understanding your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing of singular/plural with `$url` and `$urls` is at best unlucky.

If your credentials match for all sites and the `$ctx` object hasn't to be unloaded/released this could probaply work.

```
#environment variables 
$username = "user.name@xxx.com"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString
$sites = get-content "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\PowershellScripts\sites.txt"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force 

#add SharePoint Online DLL - update the location if required
$programFiles = [environment]::getfolderpath("programfiles")
add-type -Path $programFiles'\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'  

ForEach($site in $sites) {
    # connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.. 
    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site) 
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
    $ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

    #get all the sub webs
    $Web = $ctx.Web  
    $ctx.Load($web)  
    $ctx.Load($web.Webs)    
    $ctx.executeQuery()

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "There are:" $web.Webs.Count "sub webs in this site collection"
    #get all the lists 
    ForEach ($subweb in $web.Webs) {
        $lists = $subweb.Lists
        $ctx.Load($lists)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        #output the list details
        ForEach ($list in $lists) {
            if ($list.ItemCount -gt 5000) { 
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url
                Write-Host "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! LotPings. Unfortunately it doesnt work, when i run the powershell it just proceed to the next line after i put my password :(

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your script a bit using the [SharePoint PnP PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) to do the same thing. I think I got implemented what you are trying to do  :)

```
$urls = Get-Content "C:\Users\user.name\Documents\PowershellScripts\sites.txt"

$username = "user.name@xxxx.com"
$encpassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your password: " -AsSecureString

$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $encpassword

foreach($url in $urls) {
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred

    $rootweb = Get-PnPWeb -Includes Webs

    foreach($web in $rootweb.Webs) {
        $currentWeb = Get-PnPWeb $web.Id -Includes Lists

        foreach($list in $currentWeb.Lists) {
            if ($list.ItemCount -gt 5000) { 
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $currentWeb.Url
                Write-Host "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Before you can run the above script you need to install the SharePoint PnP cmdlets as well, that you can do by running

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

if you are running Windows 10. In other cases, see [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) page for more information.

With the code above I want to illustrate how you can write the same thing shorter using more high level cmdlets.

SharePoint PnP PowerShell cmdlets are cmdlets created by the SharePoint PnP community and are distributed for free to use.